# Ajax.BeginForm acting strangely after upgrading to MVC 3 and .NET 4

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have been using Ajax.form in asp.net mvc2 just fine for months. I upgraded my application to MVC3 and .net 4 and now, when posting my ajax form 
I get a dialog from the browser trying to download the json result.

here is my form

```
    <%using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "status" })) ....
```

here is the return statment in my controller

```
....
string result = "Update Successfull";
var jsonresult = result;
        return Json(jsonresult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

does MVC3 handle ajax forms differently than mvc2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC 3 uses jquery instead of MSAjax. So you might need to include the jquery unobtrusive ajax script for this to work. You also might checkout [this blog post](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-ajax.html).

Comment: thanks for your comment and link, it lead me to change my web.config file to be   <add value="false" key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" /> that fixed it. I don't fully understand the unobtrusive javascript so for now this will work for me. thanks