# ASP.NET MVC Popup Partial View on Add Form (CRUD) Issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, popup, crud, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am creating an MVC website which makes use of Partial Views on Popups to handle all my CRUD transactions. Please note that my application can already handle these CRUD operations perfectly (LINQ-To-Entity). However, I have a problem with my popup forms.

Below is the code from my `_Add.cshtml`:

```
@model MyStore.Models.MyModels.ProductsModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("_Add", "Products", new AjaxOptions
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnSuccess = "addSuccess"
}, new { @id = "addForm" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)      
    <div id="add-message" class="error invisible"></div>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Products</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.ProductCode)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Price)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Below is the code from my `Controller`:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult _Add(string productCode)
{
    ProductsModel model = newProductsModel();
    model.ProductCode = ProductCode ;
    return PartialView(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult _Add(ProductsModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ProductsManager prod = new ProductsManager();
        Products pa = new Products();

        pa.ProductCode = model.ProductCode;
        pa.ProductName = model.ProductName;
        pa.Price = model.Price;

        prod.AddProduct(pa);

        return Json(HelperClass.SuccessResponse(pa), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(HelperClass.ErrorResponse("Please review your form"), JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
    }
}
```

Please note that the `_Add.cshtml` is a partial view which is being rendered through a Popup.js which I found on the internet. It is rendered through this code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("[Add Product]", "_Add", new { ProductCode = @ViewData["ProductCode"] }, new { @class = "editLink" })
```

This works okay. I mean it adds product to my database. But my problem is upon clicking the `Proceed` button, I get this pop-up download dialog from the page:

[image: Screenshot A]

Can somebody please help me with this? I have a hunch it's because of the `HttpMethod` i'm using (POST, PUT, GET, DELETE) but i'm not really sure which one is right to use or if it really is the problem in the first place.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
PS.
Sorry for the long post.

---

**EDIT:**

This is the tutorial I followed for this project: http://ricardocovo.com/2012/04/06/asp-mvc3-editing-records-with-jqueryui-dialogs-and-ajaxforms-razor-version/

---

**EDIT:**

Below is the jscript code I am using. It's basically the same one from the tutorial I followed. I just had to comment out a few lines on the last method.

Also, I am using MVC 4. Hope this helps! Thanks!

```
var linkObj;
$(function () {
    $(".addLink").button();

    $('#addDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 400,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Update": function () {
                $("#add-message").html(''); //make sure there is nothing on the message before we continue                         
                $("#addForm").submit();
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    $(".addLink").click(function () {
        //change the title of the dialog
        linkObj = $(this);
        var dialogDiv = $('#addDialog');
        var viewUrl = linkObj.attr('href');
        $.get(viewUrl, function (data) {
            dialogDiv.html(data);
            //validation
            var $form = $("#addForm");
            // Unbind existing validation
            $form.unbind();
            $form.data("validator", null);
            // Check document for changes
            //$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document);
            // Re add validation with changes
            //$form.validate($form.data("unobtrusiveValidation").options);
            //open dialog
            dialogDiv.dialog('open');
        });
        return false;
    });

});


function addSuccess(data) {
    if (data.Success == true) {
        //we update the table's info
        //var parent = linkObj.closest("tr");
        //parent.find(".carName").html(data.Object.Name);
        //parent.find(".carDescription").html(data.Object.Description);
        //now we can close the dialog
        $('#addDialog').dialog('close');
        //twitter type notification
        $('#commonMessage').html("Add Complete");
        $('#commonMessage').delay(400).slideDown(400).delay(3000).slideUp(400);
    }
    else {
        $("#add-message").html(data.ErrorMessage);
        $("#add-message").show();
    }
}
```

I commented out these two lines:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document);
$form.validate($form.data("unobtrusiveValidation").options);
```

because not commenting them would give me the error below during runtime:
[image]

This leads me to the opinion that this issue is  due to the unobtrusive validation. Like the link posted by Xnake below, I am having the same kind of problem. The only different thing is that the Thread Opener had to disable unobtrusive validation on his Web.config file to fix the problem whereas I cannot do the same since my code is using unobtrusive validation.

Any help is greatly appreciated here. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just curious, could you please paste your js code as well? Also, since you didn't mention which MVC version you're using, this might help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4892341/605907

Comment: I tried the solution given at the thread you gave me (`<add value="false" key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" />`) but it doesn't seem to work for me. I get error messages on my javascript codes during runtime. Thank you for the response! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already fixed my problem! Apparently, I had to include the following js files on my MasterPage. Hope this helps!

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar problem when trying to find a convention for doing easily reusable popups, some CRUD some not. Rather than including the validation script on every page I added a section to my layout called `scripts` and let each page add the scripts they need (in this case, the input validation scripts if my page has form elements on it). Note that I left the Unobtrusive Ajax script on the default layout as it has nothing to do with validation and is used in enough of my pages to warrant leaving it in the default layout.

```
<html>
<head></head>
</body>
    @RenderBody()
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

In the case of Partials I created a new layout that I use only for partials that has the same section defined but no other surrounding HTML.

```
@RenderBody()
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

This is a pretty primitive example (especially since it has no visible form elements) but you get the idea.

```
@model Product
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ModalLayout.cshtml";
}
@section Scripts
{
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
<section>
    <header><h3>Remove Product?</h3></header>
    Are you sure you wish to remove @Model.Name?
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ProductId)
        <input type="submit" value="Remove" />
    }
</section>
```

Comment: very helpful and elegant indeed! thanks for this! bounty goes to you sir! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you return JSON data in _Add (post) thus the browser tries to download it instead of rendering it. Try returning the same PartialView as ActionResult instead in _Add (post). Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the response. I already tried changing the return type to an ActionResult and returning the PartialView. However, when I did this the system would just redirect me to a page similar to the Add Form I used. it's just like it renders the partial view into a new webpage. If it may help, this is where I patterned my code: http://ricardocovo.com/2012/04/06/asp-mvc3-editing-records-with-jqueryui-dialogs-and-ajaxforms-razor-version/

Answer (score 0):

This probably happens because the javascript events are not properly binded or the results is not being handled in JS.

Comment: Hi Sir Covo! I already added the jScript code I am using. It's basically the same one in your tutorial. I just had to change a few naming conventions. Thank you very much!